# How can I force cherrypy to accept a variable number of GET parameters?

Tags: python, cherrypy

for instance, say I have my cherrypy index module set up like this

```
>>> import cherrypy
>>> class test:
        def index(self, var = None):
            if var:
                print var
            else:
                print "nothing"
        index.exposed = True

>>> cherrypy.quickstart(test())
```

If I send more than one GET parameter I get this error

> 404 Not Found
>
> Unexpected query string parameters:
>   var2
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\cherrypy_cprequest.py",
>   line 606, in respond
>       cherrypy.response.body = self.handler()   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\cherrypy_cpdispatch.py",
>   line 27, in **call**
>       test_callable_spec(self.callable, self.args, self.kwargs)   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\cherrypy_cpdispatch.py",
>   line 130, in test_callable_spec
>       "parameters: %s" % ", ".join(extra_qs_params)) HTTPError:
>   (404, 'Unexpected query string
>   parameters: var2')
>
> Powered by CherryPy 3.1.2

Comment: Please unaccept my answer and accept the correct answer from Coady so that I can delete mine.

Answer (score 37):

```
def index(self, var=None, **params):
```

or

```
def index(self, **params):
```

'var2' will be a key in the params dict.  In the second example, so will 'var'.

Note the other answers which reference the *args syntax won't work in this case, because CherryPy passes query params as keyword arguments, not positional arguments.  Hence you need the ** syntax.

Answer (score 1):

For complete generality, change

```
    def index(self, var = None):
```

to

```
    def index(self, *vars):
```

`vars` will be bound to a tuple, which is empty if no arguments were passed, has one item if one argument was passed, two if two, and so forth.  It's then up to your code to deal with various such cases sensibly and appropriately, of course.